# What is the best practice for listening to payments on the RPC api?

Tags: json-rpc, full-node, deposit

I have a docker instance running a bitcoin node and would like to listen to deposits, generating a new address each time a user requests to deposit then increment the users account balance on success.

Comment: Hey, this looks like you are in need of PoS software, as you'd have to implement a lot on top of bitcoin core to achieve this. You can look into btcpay server which is free OS PoS on top of bitcoin core?

Answer (score 2):

Bitcoin has `walletnotify` feature that will notify you when an address you own in your wallet receives a transaction, and a second notification when the transaction confirms.

You can set it in your `bitcoin.conf`

`walletnotify= curl http://yoururl.com/endpoint.php?tx=%s`

`%s` will contain the transaction id. What you do from there is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from `walletnotify` callback these are the JSON RPC calls that you would use:

- https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/getreceivedbyaddress.html
- https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/listreceivedbyaddress.html
- https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/gettransaction.html

For these calls to work, you need to have a corresponding wallet created or imported into Bitcoin Core. It is also a good idea to set `txindex=1` so you can add pre-existing wallets to Core add hoc.

PS Depending on your specific use case it may be better to use existing open source, self hosted solutions like legendary [BTCPay Server](https://btcpayserver.org/) or more recent [CypherpunkPay](https://cypherpunkpay.org) (disclosure: the author).